# White screen after build on Android MAC UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, android-install-apk

The screen (on my android devices: *I tested different android devices, same issue*) is completely white after Build and Run. Not showing anything! except for the game name on the top. I also tried only Build, and then installing the APK into the phone, but same issue.

Although Build is successful, nothing wrong with it. In the console just shows some warnings (the yellow ones), and of course it says

```
Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

But apparently it's not that successful. The game runs perfectly well in unity, but nothing shows when apk is installed on my phone.

I Appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: have you tried any debugging? https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/205485376-How-do-you-debug-on-Android-

Comment: @lockstock I've looked into your link, couldn't follow it, couldn't quite get it how to go about it, its a bit advanced for me, 
Do you know any other guide?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
Ok, I've found the problem,
Well, my project was from unity 5.5.5, but my unity was version 2018.x.

I installed unity 5.5.5 in another directory on my MAC (so now I have both unity installed at the same time).
Then, I opened the project with unity 5.5.5, everything worked well and the build was fine!

So, easy thing to do is to always open your project with unity version which it was saved with, it will take a lot of headaches away from you.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that was Nexus 6p(Android 8.0) occurred.
Because I was able to solve a problem, I share it.

・Add follows in Android Manifest